# Нужное кол-во пикселей Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pil, pillow

Есть код:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import random
image = Image.new("RGBA", (320,320), (0,0,0,0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

letters_simbols_nums = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', ' ', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', str(chr(92)), ']', "^", "_", "`", '\n']

colors = [255, 254, 253, 252, 251, 250, 249, 248, 247, 246, 245, 244, 243, 242, 241, 240, 239, 238, 237, 236, 235, 234, 233, 232, 231, 230, 229, 228, 227, 226, 225, 224, 223, 222, 221, 220, 219, 218, 217, 216, 215, 214, 213, 212, 211, 210, 209, 208, 207, 206, 205, 204, 203, 202, 201, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 190, 189, 188, 187, 186, 185, 184, 183, 182, 181, 180, 179, 178, 177, 176, 175, 174, 173, 172, 171, 170, 169, 168, 167, 166, 165, 164]
f = open("text.txt", 'r')
text = f.read()
f.close()
text = list(text)

length = len(text)

if length % 2 == 0:
    image = Image.new("RGBA", (int(length / 2), int(length / 2)), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

    for y in range(0, int(length / 2)):
        for x in range(0, int(length / 2)):
            if len(text) > 0:
                simbol = text[0]
                pos = letters_simbols_nums.index(simbol)
                color = colors[pos]
                draw.point((x, y), fill=(color, 255, 255))
                text.pop(0)
            else:
                del draw
                image.save('test.png')
                exit()
```

Мне нужно, чтобы изображение которое я сохраняю было размером на то кол-во пикселей, которые я нарисовал.

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, для чего все это нужно. Непонятна цель задачи. Кст, вместо `str(chr(92))` можно написать `'\\'`, там будет один символ \, т.к. экранирование

Comment: @gil9red Это своего рода шифровальщик, определенный символ имеет свой цвет пикселя. Допустим у меня есть текст на 500 символов. Прога рисует на холсте 500 пикселей разных оттенков белого.  Всё работает, но картинка получается не 250x250px

Comment: 500 символов -> 250x250 -> 62500 пикселей . Для упрощения, если у вас будет текст в 6 символов, это это будет 3x3, а там уже 9 пикселей

Comment: @gil9red И как это решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было только правильно определить примерный размер картинки, чтобы все символы рационально влезли в картинку.

Для упрощения и красоты рисуем квадратную картинку.

Накидал [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5c76d857d9d485048e193a7a2b82144d2362324c/pil_pillow__examples/text_to_pixels/main.py#L54):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


letters_simbols_nums = [
    'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l',
    'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', 'A', 'S',
    'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', ' ', '!', '"', '#', '$',
    '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
    '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', "^", "_", "`", '\n'
]
colors = [
    255, 254, 253, 252, 251, 250, 249, 248, 247, 246, 245, 244, 243, 242, 241, 240, 239, 238, 237, 236, 235, 234,
    233, 232, 231, 230, 229, 228, 227, 226, 225, 224, 223, 222, 221, 220, 219, 218, 217, 216, 215, 214, 213, 212,
    211, 210, 209, 208, 207, 206, 205, 204, 203, 202, 201, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 190,
    189, 188, 187, 186, 185, 184, 183, 182, 181, 180, 179, 178, 177, 176, 175, 174, 173, 172, 171, 170, 169, 168,
    167, 166, 165, 164
]

image = Image.new("RGBA", (320, 320), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

text = """\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id 
est laborum.
"""
items = list(text)

# Подбираем размер, наиболее близкий к длине текста
img_size = -1
for s in range(2, 1000):
    if s * s >= len(items):
        img_size = s
        break

assert img_size != -1, "Неудалось подобрать размер изображения"

image = Image.new("RGBA", (img_size, img_size), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

for y in range(img_size):
    for x in range(img_size):
        if not items:
            break

        simbol = items.pop(0)
        pos = letters_simbols_nums.index(simbol)
        color = colors[pos]
        draw.point((x, y), fill=(color, 255, 255))

image.save('result.png')
```

Результат (размер 22x22 пикселя):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат (с масштабом):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]